# What should be the checkpoints if the bounce rate drops below 40%?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, bounce-rate

We did quite a few changes on the website over the last 2 months and apart from the events triggered what else should I be looking at to investigate the dropped bounce rate?

Comment: Bounce rate is dropped below 40% so it’s a positive signal.  It means your site, pages and content is more engaging and your users are browsing multiple pages on your site. You should try to reduce bounce rate as max as possible

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I will not recommend analyzing the whole site bounce rate. You should analyze sections or URL type. That's because a blog, a landing or a corporate URL would have different user behavior and therefore different bounce rate.

On the second hand, in order to check the bouncing drop you can check:

- Events (nonInteraction option, you already did that).
- Duplicate code / iframe with code.
- Changes to the content/menu/structure of the site. (for example, one URL with section navigation (internal anchor text) changed to multiple URLs)

Comment: Thank you for the response...we did a few url changes and we moved a few important pages to the main domain from a sub domain. will check again on your third point.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)